# No sound from P51 docking station

Tags: sound

I get sound from my P51 / Xubuntu 17.04 if plugged in the laptop directly but not from the docking station if laptop resides in the station.
I think I have tried all recommended steps for other Lenovo models regarding the configuration file (alsa-base.conf) and even tried all possibilities from HDAJackRetask without success.
Also I called my dealer and he said that the P51 laptop IS Ubuntu certified but the docking station is NOT - so he can't help me in any way :-(

Has anybody managed to get this working?
Possibly interesting are people that got the sound working for the P50 (predecessor of the P51) in the docking station since the docking station seems to be absolutely the same.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: I've no experience with this laptop or it's docking station. But in the case of a DisplayLink docking station (which adds an additional sound device), one have to change the output device under `Sound Settings`, `Output`-tab. Have you checked there? If it's more of a `passthrough` docking station, are you booting the laptop with it connected in the docking station? On both my dell laptops, I have no sound if I boot them with headphones plugged in. Sometimes that can be fixed with a `pulseaudio -k`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes I have tried all possibilities in Sound Settings (which made sound working at least for the internal jack of the laptop) but that did not do the trick for the docking station. I can see the device and chose it, but still no sound. Also I have tried booting in the docking station with speakers connected / not connected: all makes no difference....

Comment: Found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1630860 seems very relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I have a P51 and have the same problem. There is no audio when the laptop is connected to the docking station AND IF a headset or external speakers are connected to the docking station. Unplugging the headset from the docking station has solved the problem for me (at least partially). Connecting the headset to the laptop itself works, too - even when the laptop is connected to the docking station.