# Dell XPS + dock WD19 - speakers not work

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, dell, alsa

I have a problem with speakers connected via jack to docking station Dell WD19. Outputs seem to be detected but the sound does not play.

```
╰>  aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Dock [WD19 Dock], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Dock [WD19 Dock], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC289 Analog [ALC289 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Headset [Wireless Stereo Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Two outputs on card 1 seem to be jack in the front and back of the dock - the rest are built-in speakers, monitors and usb connected headset.

Here's output from `pacmd list-cards`:

```
index: 5
name: <alsa_card.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 28
properties:
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "WD19 Dock"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Dell-WD15-Dock"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5.3.4:1.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.3/1-5.3.4/1-5.3.4:1.0/sound/card1"
    udev.id = "usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00"
    device.bus = "usb"
    device.vendor.id = "0bda"
    device.vendor.name = "Realtek Semiconductor Corp."
    device.product.id = "402e"
    device.product.name = "USB Audio"
    device.serial = "Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001"
    device.string = "1"
    device.description = "USB Audio"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
profiles:
    HiFi: Default (priority 8000, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <HiFi>
sinks:
    alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock_1__sink/#10: USB Audio Line Out
    alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock__sink/#11: USB Audio Headphones
sources:
    alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock_1__sink.monitor/#16: Monitor of USB Audio Line Out
    alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock__sink.monitor/#17: Monitor of USB Audio Headphones
    alsa_input.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00.HiFi__hw_Dock__source/#18: USB Audio Microphone
ports:
    [Out] Line: Line Out (priority 200, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            
    [Out] Headphones: Headphones (priority 100, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            
    [In] Mic: Microphone (priority 100, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
```

Now, when I open sound settings I can see a number of devices:

[image: sound settings]

When I select any Wireless Stereo Headset, HDMI 2 or Speakers Built-in appropriate device does make sound. But when I select USB Audio (Headset or Line Out) everything is quiet - even though the volume is set to 100%. I am running out of ideas what else could I check to fix this...

(exact same setup works fine when I switch to Windows so it's not a hardware issue)

[EDIT]
Adding requested output from certain commands:

```
====================================== cat /proc/asound/cards ======================================

 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x604b118000 irq 181
 1 [Dock           ]: USB-Audio - WD19 Dock
                      Dell-WD15-Dock
 2 [C920           ]: USB-Audio - HD Pro Webcam C920
                      HD Pro Webcam C920 at usb-0000:00:14.0-5.3.3.4, high speed

========================================= lsmod | grep snd =========================================

snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_sof_pci            24576  0
snd_sof_intel_byt      20480  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    81920  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof               122880  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    45056  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_acpi           16384  3 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_soc_core          278528  3 snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_codec_realtek   139264  1
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_sof,dell_laptop
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         143360  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           94208  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_usb_audio         286720  5
snd_usbmidi_lib        36864  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_pcm               118784  10 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    94208  31 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mc                     57344  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common

=========================== dpkg -L linux-modules-$(uname -r) | grep snd ===========================

/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-dummy.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-emul.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-event.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-virmidi.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-compress.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hrtimer.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm-dmaengine.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-rawmidi.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-seq-device.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/pcsp/snd-pcsp.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-ens1370.ko

============================================= inxi -SA =============================================

System:    Host: tkaplonski-xps-jobleads Kernel: 5.8.0-48-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.6.7 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla) 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: Logitech type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
           Device-3: Realtek type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-48-generic 

=================================== lspci -nnk | grep -A 4 Audio ===================================

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS [8086:06c8]
    Subsystem: Dell Comet Lake PCH cAVS [1028:097d]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller [8086:06a3]

============================================= uname -a =============================================

Linux tkaplonski-xps-jobleads 5.8.0-48-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 14:25:20 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

======================================= dpkg -l | grep alsa ========================================

ii  alsa-base                                  1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-tools-gui                             1.2.2-1                             amd64        GUI based ALSA utilities for specific hardware
ii  alsa-topology-conf                         1.2.3-1                             all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                              1.2.2-1ubuntu5.1                    all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.2.3-1ubuntu1                      amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                    1.18.0-2                            amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA

============================ grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf =============================

options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
```

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting here a few things to try.
Some were taken from old threads/solutions/etc., so they may not apply.

1. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457978/no-sound-from-chrome-sound-works-fine-in-firefox-etc-13-10/668329#668329) (reboot after issuing the commands)

   ```
   killall pulseaudio
   rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*
   rm -r ~/.pulse*
   ```
2. Install `pavucontrol` and tinker with its controls. I am not sure what you will see there.
3. [This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1464321/comments/9): "*changing the configuration in "Pulse Audio Volume Control" from "Analog Duplex" to "Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input".*" Look for analogous settings.
4. Go to system sound settings and set output to lineout ([ref](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/bg3a1k/tb16_dock_no_sound_on_line_out_with_xps_9570_and/)) (not sure if you tried alternatives for this)
5. Since the driver seems to be `snd_usb_audio`, try a solution like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/705407/226614), adapted somehow to your case.

**Related**:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10070/no-sound-when-attached-to-docking-station
2. [No sound from P51 docking station](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932746/no-sound-from-p51-docking-station)
3. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1630860
4. [ThinkPad T440p docking station: no sound on external speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483174/thinkpad-t440p-docking-station-no-sound-on-external-speakers)
5. https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1311128.html
6. https://github.com/edrose/dell-dock-audio-fix/issues/2
7. https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/Latitude-5580-with-WD19-dock-Sound-defaults-to-dock-headphone/td-p/7628548
8. https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?t=54788

Comment: Thanks for this. #1 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a USB speaker where it was being detected, and would appear in `lsusb` output but wouldn't play sound, it appears to be an issue with pulseaudio, though I don't know the precise reasons, my problem was resolved by following these steps:

Open `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` in a text editor with root privileges.

Uncomment the following lines (remove the semi-colon `;`):

```
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 48000
```

Make sure the sample rate is set to `48000`.

A preliminary look at the Windows drivers for this dock show the supported audio modes as:

```
48k_16bit_2ch
48k_24bit_2ch
96k_16bit_2ch
96k_24bit_2ch
192k_24bit_2ch
192k_16bit_2ch
```

Reboot your PC.

Hopefully this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

*A comment posted as an answer, as it won't fit otherwise.*

it may help if you post the output of:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
$ lsmod | grep snd
$ dpkg -L linux-modules-<kernel version>-generic | grep snd
$ inxi -SA
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A 4 Audio
$ uname -a
$ dpkg -l | grep alsa
$ grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

It helped a lot [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul).

Comment: Added requested output in edit to original question.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to look at: in terminal, open `alsamixer`. Press `F6` to bring up the menu with the available soundcards. Go around in each of them, and ensure that the `PCM` volume bar (column) is not set to `0 <> 0` (`0` volume level for left and right channel correspondingly.)

If yes, use the right / left arrows to select the column, and up arrow to increase the value.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with my XPS 13 7390 running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS plus WD 19 and treid all above suggested steps without sucess. To make sure that it's not a hardware issue I connected my old XPS 13 which has Win 10. On Windows line out works fine - so it is not a hardware issue. After this I plugged my new XPS and ... magic ... suddenly line out is working and still after a reboot!

This is really strange!!!

Comment: I noticed even weirder magic in fact. My sounds sometimes works after restart and sometimes it does not. For some time I thought there was a rule depending on which thunderbolt I used (there are two ports on the left that can be used) but that's not the case - sometimes one work the other does not and sometimes roles turn. It's totally crazy but at least I know I can always reboot/plug cable into different port :/